# downolading a file in angular 8 using asp.net core 2.1 always give corrupted file

Tags: c#, angular8, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using asp.net core 2.1 in my project and angular 8 for client side but unable to make feature for downolad a file, while downloading it only download .txt file and unable to download .pdf,.excell,image etc.Below is my code.

```
downloadFiles(filename: any) {   
    return this.http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Download/' + filename)
    .catch(this.errorHandler)
}

//after getting response data from server and passing to the method makeDownloadFiles only 
//downloded corrupted file.

makeDownloadFiles(data: any) {
    debugger;
    const blob = new Blob([data]); 
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}

//and server code is 

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Download/{filename}")]
public FileResult Download(string filename){
    try {
        string extension = filename.Substring(filename.IndexOf('.') + 1);
        string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/files", filename);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        string fileName = filename;
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm if you make a text file with the text '123456789' in it, you can compare the file with the downloaded file and see if maybe some text is cut off or the bytes have shifted somewhere. Maybe the encoding is even off (just thinking out of the top of my head here)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just try this. you don't need to call api of api/download file. Just get FileUrl and call below method.

```
 downloadFile(fileNameUrl: any) {

        var filename: string[] = fileNameUrl.split('\\');
        this.getImage(fileNameUrl).subscribe((data: Blob) => {
            debugger;
            let item = filename[filename.length - 1];

            let checkFileType = item.split('.').pop();
            var fileType: any;
            if (checkFileType == "txt") {
                fileType = "text/plain";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "pdf") {
                fileType = "application/pdf";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "doc") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "docx") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "xls") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "xlsx") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "png") {
                fileType = "image/png";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "jpg") {
                fileType = "image/jpeg";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "jpeg") {
                fileType = "image/jpeg";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "gif") {
                fileType = "image/gif";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "csv") {
                fileType = "text/csv";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "amr") {
                fileType = "AMR-WB";
            }
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: fileType })
            const blob1: Blob = data;
            const fileName1: string = item;
            const objectUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a') as HTMLAnchorElement;

            a.href = objectUrl;
            a.download = fileName1;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

            document.body.removeChild(a);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        })
        }

  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this._http.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you brother it works as I expected,thank yo so much,keep helping.

Answer (score 0):

Once I specified types in the call to `get` and the call to `new Blob` your code worked fine:

```
downloadFiles(filename: any) {   
    return this.http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Download/' + filename, { responseType: 'blob'})
    .catch(this.errorHandler)
}

makeDownloadFiles(data: any) {
    debugger;
    const blob = new Blob([<any>data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}); 
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```